# How to ignore a file which is already committed?

Tags: git, gitignore

Previously, the following was my `.gitignore` file:

```
...
config/database.yml
.DS_Store
```

Later I created an `app_config.yml` file in the config directory and committed it.

Now, I realized that I don't need the `app_config.yml` file in the git repository.
And I modified my `.gitignore` file:

```
...
config/app_config.yml
config/database.yml
.DS_Store
```

Now, when I commit, that `app_config.yml` file is still in my repo. 
I want to remove that file from my repo. How can I do it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As mentionned in "[ignoring doesn't remove a file](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/06/ignoring-doesnt-remove-a-file.html) "
(the following quote the great article from **Nick Quaranto**,
in his blog [**git ready**](http://gitready.com/) "learn git one commit at a time"):

> **When you tell Git to ignore files, it’s going to only stop watching changes for that file, and nothing else.
>
>   This means that the history will still remember the file and have it**.
>
> If you want to remove a file from the repository, but keep it in your working directory, simply use:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

> However, this will still keep the file in history.
>
> If you actually want to remove it from history, you really have two options:
>
> - rewrite your repository’s commits, or
> - start over.
>
> Both options really suck, and that’s for a good reason: Git tries hard not to lose your data.
>   Just like with rebasing, Git forces you to think about these kinds of options since they are destructive operations.
>
> If you did actually want to remove a file from history, **`git filter-branch`** is the hacksaw you’re looking for.
>   Definitely read up on its **[manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)** before using it, since it will literally rewrite your project’s commits. This actually is a great tool for some actions, and can do all sorts of stuff like totally removing an author’s commits to moving the project root folder around. The command to remove a file from all revisions is:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached <file>' HEAD
```

> This action can definitely be useful when you need to blow out sensitive or confidential information that may have been placed in your repository

Answer (score 6):

that doesn't help when you want to start ignoring a file that is committed and you want to keep it in the project... since **git rm --cached**  would delete it from git repo...

I found this [How do I stop Git from tracking any changes to a file from this commit forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276951/how-do-i-stop-git-from-tracking-any-changes-to-a-file-from-this-commit-forward/18277622) which is what I was looking for..

hopefully it's useful for other people as well...