# How to ignore files which are in repository?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-rm

I have a file (`config.php`), that is already committed to a Git repository, but I want to ignore locally, i.e. I want that file to remain in repository, but force Git to ignore any changes to it.

I put the file into `.gitignore`, but it is still marked as changed and Git still is attempting to commit changes to it, every time I commit something.

Any ideas, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: please add your .gitignore-file - that way we might see any problems regarding it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore a file which is already comitted in the previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625919/how-to-ignore-a-file-which-is-already-comitted-in-the-previous-commit)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

If the file is still displayed in the status, even though it is in the .gitignore, make sure it isn't already tracked.

```
git rm --cached config.php
```

If you just want to ignore it locally, you could also make it ignored by the git status:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config.php
```

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231608/how-to-ignore-files-which-are-in-repository/7232354#comment115290716_7232354), do note that using `--assume-unchanged` might cause unwanted data loss as [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) resets the "ignored" files to the state in upstream, undoing local changes, without a warning or saving.

Comment: OK thanks ! If I merge my branch with another, can this file makes some problems ?

Comment: @Nimbus147: it shouldn't be an issue, and any changes on that file will still be ignored (ie not added/committed).

Comment: if use SmartGit, you should use remove to do this.

Comment: `git rm --cached config.php` will error out: `fatal: pathspec 'config.php' did not match any files`. What to do?

Comment: @San Do you have a config.phone file displayed by git status?

Comment: Can you help me in [my situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349901/how-to-track-untracked-files-in-git)? I would appreciate it really

Comment: Is there a way to force `update-index --assume-unchanged` on the remote branch? I'd like to keep the file in the repo, but not be able to be changed by others but moreover not available to stage.

Comment: @p014k Not that I know of. For that kind of file, I keep it versioned under a different name, then use a content filer driver to automatically generate the right file (private) when needed. That filter would not be active on stage for instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54454356/6309 and its associated link.

Comment: So it sounds like one can't ignore changes to a file that is part of the repo.

Comment: @Nick Indeed. You would need content filter driver to simulate partially ignoring a file content: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59484661/6309

Comment: Using --assume-unchanged might cause unwanted data loss as `git stash` resets the "ignored" files to the state in upstream, undoing local changes, without a warning or saving.

Comment: @user3351650 Thank you, very good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: This tried to delete my file.  I don't want it deleted, I want it ignored.

Comment: @GringoSuave Do you mean "delete from the disk"? Because a `git rm --cached` should *keep* the file on your disk, not delete it. Only untrack it from Git, which is needed if you want the .gitignore to have any effect on it.

Comment: Yes, git status said it would remove file from repo, not delete the file.  If the feature is not available, not your fault, however.

Comment: @GringoSuave Removing it from the repository is the expected outcome, in order to make the `.gitignore` effective, and actually ignoring the file (which is still on the disk, but no longer tracked in the repository)

Comment: From the question, "I want that file to remain in repository, but force Git to ignore any changes to it."  Removing it is *not* the expected outcome.  Personally need for everyone to ignore it, not just me, so the second command doesn't help either.

Comment: @GringoSuave Interesting: the file should be part of the repository history, but should never change? I usually remove it from the repo, keep a template file in the repo, with placeholder values in it, and use a content filter driver to generate a private (Ie: "non-tracked") file automatically on git checkout/restore. Example: the last section of my previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71391591/6309

Answer (score 9):

Ignore checked in file:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file
```

To revert

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file
```

Revert All

```
git update-index --really-refresh
```

Comment: Helpful. Revert one file worked but revert all didn't, though.

Answer (score 4):

If the file is already in the repository, and hence the Index/Staging area, then an update to `.gitignore` won't change that situation. It would keep being committed.

To remove the file from the Index/Staging area use `git rm <file>`.

Comment: What if file is in the repository but is not staged yet? I am trying to ignore *.log files, but I still see them under "Changes". I want to ignore all, what to do?

Comment: @SandraK if there is an older version of that file (filepath/name) already in the repo at the last commit, then it is considered tracked - the 'index' will have that file in its records, and so `status` will continue to tell you about those changes. If you want to ignore *.log files, for both previously tacked and currently untracked fles, then you need to both `git rm *.log` and update your .gitignore file. Do check first if some log files are actually important... It is easy to forget that special one ;-)