# How to use "!" in .gitignore as a string

Tags: git, gitignore

I have directory which starts with exclamation mark, like:

```
!test
```

I want to add it in gitignore, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
\!test
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can escape it with a backslash => `\!test`

Comment: @Eugene I think it is ok, have tested it on my machine (git version 1.8.3.4). Make sure that you can't ignore a file already tracked, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231608/git-ignore-files-which-are-on-repository).

Comment: @Eugene no didn't try it, but i know you can escape special chars with a backslash

Comment: @Eugene I tried. It works. Please, mark the answer as correct.