# problem with ignoring files/folders that are already in the remote repository (github)

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitignore

I am working on PhpStorm. There are some files/folders that I would like git to ignore. These are on the remote repository, too. I just don't want to reflect any more changes about them but they have to stay - not be deleted - from remote repo since I am going to pull from this repo to the production server.

- I have added them to the .gitignore file which is in the project root.
- I have added them to PhpStorm Settings > Version Control > Ignored Files section as described here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000154070-How-to-gitignore-idea-files
- [How to ignore files which are in repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231608/how-to-ignore-files-which-are-in-repository) this question describes my problem exactly, yet I have tried both methods which are described in the accepted answer, here is what happened:

  - `git rm -r --cached .idea/`
    I did this and related files/folders were deleted from my remote repository too, which I don't want because I think it will result in deleting those when I pull on the production server.
  - `git update-index --assume-unchanged .idea/`
    I did this, "Ignoring path .idea/" was written in the terminal, I hoped that it would work but when I wanted to commit, I saw that folder again as tracked.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: .idea folder may not be important for the production server, but there are some important folders needed for the code to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered where I was wrong. For those who may need, I will explain it with two folders I have:

- config/ and config.php under it
- pdf/ and pdf.css under it

So:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree config/
```

Running this and changing config.php didn't help. On the other hand:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree pdf/
```

After running this I got a pdf output from my web application and it created pdf.html also under pdf/ folder. So, this new file was ignored, good.

Shortly, I concluded that I had to point out the exact file if that's what I want to be ignored, like this:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree config/config.php
```

It ignores any changes to this file afterwards.

(I tried the same with `--assume-unchanged`, it worked, yet since I have understood the difference very well from the answer above, I wanted to highlight the better way here)

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't use `--assume-unchanged` to ignore tracked files

The purpose of the [`--assume-unchanged`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-assume-unchanged) flag is to tell Git to avoid checking the files in specific path for changes, because they *aren't supposed to change*.

From the [documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit):

> setting this bit on a path does not mean Git will check the contents of the file to see if it has changed — it makes Git to omit any checking and assume it has not changed.

This feature exists as a performance optimization in case your repo has very large files and/or a slow file system.

As Junio C Hamano [points out](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/gitignore-vs-exclude-vs-assume-unchanged-tp7607901p7607919.html) in a discussion thread about the [difference between .gitignore and --assume-unchanged](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/gitignore-vs-exclude-vs-assume-unchanged-td7607901.html):

> Assume-unchanged should not be abused for an ignore mechanism.  It
>   is "I know my filesystem operations are slow.  I'll promise Git that
>   I won't change these paths by making them with that bit.

He goes on:

> Especially, it is *not* a promise by Git that Git will always
>   consider these paths are unmodified---if Git can determine a path
>   that is marked as assume-unchanged has changed without incurring
>   extra `lstat(2)` cost, it reserves the right to report that the path
>   *has been* modified (as a result, `git commit -a` is free to commit
>   that change).

In other words, if a file in a path marked with `--assume-unchanged` is modified, Git may decide to ignore the flag if doing so isn't too slow of an operation. This is probably why you're seeing the files in the `.idea/` directory as modified.

#### Use `--skip-worktree` instead

There's another way you can tell Git to ignore the changes in path, and that's by setting the [`--skip-worktree`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-skip-worktree) flag.

From the [documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit):

> When reading an entry, if it is marked as skip-worktree, then Git pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the index version instead.

You can substitute the word *entry* with the word *path*. The difference between `--skip-worktree` and `--assume-unchanged` is in the *assumption* they make: while `--assume-unchanged` expects the files not to be modified, `--skip-worktree` doesn't care about the state of the files in the working directory at all.

The [documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit) says as much:

> The working directory version may be present or absent. If present, its content may match against the index version or not.

Once a path as been marked with `--skip-worktree`, Git will go out of its way to exclude any local modifications made to the files in the working directory from the history of the repo.

Comment: Actually, I realized that I was doing something wrong; I will explain it as an answer. Nevertheless your explanation is great, I have read it thorougly and learnt well.