# Git manage environment specific configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, git, git-fork

I have a requirement to have a property configuration for different environment like dev, uat and production. For example a config.properties having and entry like `environment=dev`, this I need to change for staging branch as `environment=uat` and for master branch as `environment=prd` .

I tried to commit these files in each branch respectively and tried adding config.properties in gitignore so that it will not consider in next commits.
But git ignore not getting updated so I ran command

```
git rm -rf --cached src/config.properties
git add src/config.properties
git commit -m ".gitignore fix"
```

But this command is deleting the file from local repository itself and the proceeding commits also deleting from branches. I want to handle the branch as such so as Jenkins will do the deployment without editing config file manually. I am using fork for git UI. Is there any way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: while merging your dev branch to uat, don't commit that file.then uat Will use its from config.properties

Answer (score 7):

You should not version a `config.properties` (`git rm` is right), and ignore it indeed.
That way, it won't pose any issue during merge.

It is easier to have three separate files, one per environment:

- `config.properties.dev`
- `config.properties.uat`
- `config.properties.prd`

In each branch, you would then *generate* `config.properties`, with the right value in it, from one of those files, depending on the current execution environment.

Since you have separate branches per environment, with the right file in it, you can have a generation script which will determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

That means you could:

- version only a template file `config.properties.<env>`
- version value files named after the branches: `config.properties.dev`, `config.properties.uat`...: since they are different, there is no merge issue when merging or switching branches.

Finally, you would register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script, associated to the template file (`package.json.tpl`), would generate (automatically, on `git checkout`) the actual `config.properties` file by looking values in the right `config.properties.<env>` value file.
The generated actual `config.properties` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".