# git is telling me to commit or stash changes to excluded file using --skip-worktree when trying to checkout to new branch

Tags: git

I have some files that are excluded from git changes.
I can changes the file locally, and the changes is not shown in the `git status`.

But, if I try to squash the branch or, try to checkout to new branch, it doesn't allow me to do so, without committing the changes to those file.

How can I manage those files?

Answer (score 0):

> or, try to checkout to new branch, it doesn't allow me to do so, without committing the changes to those file.

That is why Git 2.25.1 (Feb. 2020) now includes in [`git update-index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1b13e9032f039c8cdb1994dd092ff2ed32af5cf5/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L552-L567):

> Users often try to use the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits to tell Git to ignore changes to files that are tracked.
>
> This does not work as expected, since Git may still check working tree files against
>   the index when performing certain operations.
>   In general, Git does not provide a way to ignore changes to tracked files, so alternate solutions are recommended.
>
> For example, if the file you want to change is some sort of config file, the repository can include a sample config file that can then be copied into the ignored name and modified.
>   The repository can even include a script to treat the sample file as a template, modifying and copying it automatically.

I reference the last part in a [content filter driver based on smudge/clean scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59484661/6309).

Comment: having sample file and copying it is not an option for me me unfortunately, since, the file needs to be changed and pushed by other members.

Comment: @priosshrsth The content filter driver means you have a private file generate, while an official file (with different name) can still be changed and pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that those files are some configuration files. I'd suggest the following approach. Let Git know about the changes:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree EACH_FILE
```

Stash those changes:

```
git stash save "Save local conf"
```

You can now checkout to the other branch without problems, then restore your local changes:

```
git stash pop
```

and you can fix the conflicts, if any, accepting your local changes.